# Safari 6 (iOS 6) flex layout doesn't wrap elements

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I need the two boxes to be in columns. This works in other browsers I have tested but not in Safari 6 on iOS 6.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/5FESj/1/

```
display: -webkit-box;
-webkit-box-direction: normal;
-webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
-webkit-box-align: center;
```

I need to use row (horizontal) layout, I just want all elements that go over 100% to get pushed to the next line.

Comment: Support for the [current flexbox spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/) in iOS didn't begin until iOS 7.0. iOS 6 supports the old flexbox spec and *doesn't support wrapping*. http://stackoverflow.com/a/33199966/3597276

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/73agg/)**</kbd>

HTML

```
<div class="page-wrap">
    <div class="content1">
         <h1>DIV 1</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="content2">
         <h2>DIV 2</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.page-wrap > div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: lightBlue;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.page-wrap {
    display: -webkit-box;
    /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
    display: -moz-box;
    /* OLD - Firefox 19- (doesn't work very well) */
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
    display: -webkit-flex;
    /* NEW - Chrome */
    display: flex;
    /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
}
.content1 {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 1;
    /* OLD - Firefox 19- */
    -ms-flex-order: 1;
    /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
    -webkit-order: 1;
    /* NEW - Chrome */
    order: 1;
    /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
    min-width:200px;
    width: 50%;
    /* No flex here, other cols take up remaining space */
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    /* Without this, Firefox 19- expands to widest paragraph, overrides width */
}
.content2 {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
    /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 2;
    /* OLD - Firefox 19- */
    -ms-flex-order: 2;
    /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
    -webkit-order: 2;
    /* NEW - Chrome */
    order: 2;
    /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
    -webkit-box-flex: 2;
    /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
    -moz-box-flex: 2;
    /* Firefox 19- */
    /* For OLD syntax, otherwise collapses. */
    min-width:200px;
    -ms-flex: 2;
    /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
    -webkit-flex: 2;
    /* NEW - Chrome */
    flex: 2;
    /* NEW, Spec - Opera 12.1, Firefox 20+ */
    background: #ccc;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .page-wrap {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

References : ([1](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/05/22/centering-elements-with-flexbox/)) ([2](http://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/))

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/73agg/3/)</kbd>

css

```
@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .page-wrap {
        flex-direction: column-reverse;
    }
}
```

[Refer](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: Hmm you set display: block for the wrapper, is it not possible with using flex?

Comment: Yes by using flex-direction: column-reverse; see the edited demo

Comment: So this is a bug in Safari 6 where elements don't wrap like a normal grid layout using horizontal layout and flex?

Comment: the flexbox layout is direction-agnostic as opposed to the regular layouts (block which is vertically-based and inline which is horizontally-based). While those work well for pages, they lack flexibility to support large or complex applications (especially when it comes to orientation changing, resizing, stretching, shrinking, etc.).

Note: Flexbox layout is most appropriate to the components of an application, and small-scale layouts, while the Grid layout is intended for larger scale layouts. (http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)