# Flex-wrap in Safari 6 and lower

Tags: html, ios, css, safari, flexbox

I'm trying to create a website and I was hoping to use flexbox to help with my layout.  I've gotten it to work with most of the popular browsers except Safari below version 6.1.  The main problem I'm having is with flex-wrap.  I want the elements to automatically wrap horizontally. 
So I want the equivalent to this for Safari 6 and lower:

`display: flex;
-webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;`

Is there any way to do this? The closest I've found to an answer is that that it might not be supported (from this question here: [Safari 6 (iOS 6) flex layout doesn't wrap elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23466978/safari-6-ios-6-flex-layout-doesnt-wrap-elements)).  But it doesn't seem very clear to me. What I want to know is: is it supported? and if not, is it possible to achieve a similar affect?

Comment: Safari 6 and lower use a different (old) version of the flexbox syntax. Although I don't know how to fix your specific problem, this article may help: http://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/. Also, the website caniuse is a great resource for learning about what is supported in different browser versions: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox. Safari 6 has a pretty small number of users, so it may not even be worth your time to try and support it.

Comment: Thanks! However I already knew it used a different syntax.  My problem is specifically with the flex-wrap.  I can't seem to find the proper syntax for that.

Comment: According to a paragraph in this article: http://dev.opera.com/articles/advanced-cross-browser-flexbox/, there is no equivalent of flex-wrap in the old syntax. You might need to rethink your approach.

Answer (score 3):

## Short answer

Apparently there is no way to use the property `flex-wrap` on ios safari < 6.1.

### If you want to try a work around

Use a small Javscript test (or [Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/download?flexwrap-setclasses)) to detect the missing flexwrap property:

```
// Detects flex wrap for current browser
var has_flex_wrap_support = function () {
  let d = document.documentElement.style
  return (('flexWrap' in d) || ('WebkitFlexWrap' in d) || ('msFlexWrap' in d));
}

// Add the class no-flexwrap to body depending on result of test
var check_for_flexwrap = function () {
  if ( ! has_flex_wrap_support() )
    document.body.classList.add('no-flexwrap');
};

check_for_flexwrap();
```

Inside your css use inline-block to get a similar horizontal wrapping effect:

```
.no-flexwrap .container { display: block; }
.no-flexwrap .container__children { display: inline-block; }
```

### See also:

[Almost complete guide to flexbox without flexbox](https://kyusuf.com/post/almost-complete-guide-to-flexbox-without-flexbox).

Comment: @anora see my answer, there is no flexwrap support on ios < 6.1 but I added a work around.

Answer (score 1):

> The closest I've found to an answer is that that it might not be supported. But it doesn't seem very clear to me.

Safari < 6.1 uses [the first Flexbox specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-css3-flexbox-20090723/). At this moment (2009), there was nothing like `flex-wrap` existing.

So no, it's not supported.