# css flexbox wrap property doesn't work on ios6

Tags: html, ios, css, flexbox

I am working on my project now, so I decided to use `flexbox` instead of `float`. It works fine for me, but I've found that `display:flex` doesn't work on the old iphone (ios 6.1). So I've added

```
display: -webkit-box;
```

Flex property works now, but all items are arranged in a row. I've created a simple [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fkuk3zL7/5/), to show the problem. 
Also I've made two screenshots, to show how it works on PC and on iPhone.

PC: [image]

iPhone: [image]

As you see `-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap` doesn't work.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?? 
I hope for your help.

Comment: Duplicate question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23466978/safari-6-ios-6-flex-layout-doesnt-wrap-elements

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox reports that v6 only supports the old flexbox def and does not support wrapping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for the [current flexbox specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/) in iOS doesn't begin until iOS 7.0.

iOS 3.2 - 6.1 support the [old flexbox specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-css3-flexbox-20111129/) and *do not support wrapping*.

See browser support data here: http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

Answer (score 0):

See the [`flex-direction`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-direction) property for info on how to align the flex items (row or column).

```
.wrapper {
    flex-direction: column;
    ...
}
```

Also, on your flex items, you have (`width: 500px;`) try the [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) property:

```
.wrapper > div {
   flex: 0 0 500px;
   ...
}
```